# RebootReceiver doesn't work

Tags: android

There is the following code for AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".receivers.RebootReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>            
</receiver>
```

And code for BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class RebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DataSourceWrapper.getInstance().initializeAllNotifications();
    }

}
```

But after rebooting I've got no messages. What have I made a mistake? Android 4.0, HTC Sensation.

Answer (score 0):

you want add android manifest permission

1. add the permission to android permission `**<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>**`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the category.
Only the action is enough.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intent filter is correct:

**action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED**

Try after removing category Home

**Use permission :
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED**

check logs after rebooting phone.